# Managing stored procedures in SQL Server over time

Tags: sql-server, wcf, stored-procedures

Imagine I am creating a Winforms app, using WCF I connect the same to SQL Server. I would be creating stored procedures in SQL Server.

My scenario here is as I release updates for my app over time...like ver 1.0, ver 2.0...v.n...

I might then need to modify my stored procedures. But I can't do that as it might affect users using the earlier version of the app. Hence I might need to create new stored procedures for the newer versions over time.

So I would want to know what is the best naming convention for my stored procedures? Can I name them something like `sp_name_1_0`, `sp_name_2_0` and so on? It would have been much easier if there was some kind of grouping possible for stored procedures in SQL Server like folders...

Let me know what the best way is!

Thanks,
Sarin Gopalan

Comment: Yes, you can name your procedures with version number in the end. Please do not use sp_ as the prefix, it's meant for the system procedures. For the "grouping" of procedures, you could also use schemas, so that one version has all its procedures in one schema.

Comment: thanks james... so the name of my sp would look like ver2_0.example :)